# Add variable to each twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

How can I transfer variable to each twig template?

I need transfer rates to each template in my application.

Comment: from where comes the data for the variable?

Comment: It comes from database

Answer (score 1):

You do that by using global variables.

[How to Inject Variables into all Templates (i.e. Global Variables)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html) (I know, searching the docs is hard...)

Comment: In this case as a twig extension